# Substring search on one column from the column of another table without IN operator

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-sentinel

I have two tables in Azure one of which is a list of URLs and the other has only Domain Names. I want to be able to check if the the URLs in the URLtable "contains" the domain name from the DomainName_table. **The "in" operator cannot be used since there will never be an exact match.**
Dummy tables below:

```
let DomainName_table= datatable (domainname: string)
        [
            "abc456",
            "gmail"
        ]
        |summarize domainlist = make_list(domainname);
 let URLtable= datatable (URL: string)
        [
            "abc456/.com/ffsfd/sdfsdfds",
            "gmail",//.com/sAFSfS"
            "gmddail.com"///sAFfsdfsfSfS"
        ];
          URLtable
          | where URL in (DomainName_table)
```

I also tried to split the URL to extract the domain name :

```
let DomainName_table= datatable (domainname: string)
        [
            "abc456",
            "gmail"
        ]
        |summarize domainlist = make_list(domainname);
 let URLtable= datatable (URL: string)
        [
            "https://abc456.com/ffsfd/sdfsdfds",
            "https://gmail.com/sAFSfS"
            "https://gmddail.com/sAFfsdfsfSfS"
        ];
          URLtable
          |extend split_url = split(URL,"/",2)//| project split_url
  | where split_url in (DomainName_table)
```

This is also not a great way since it can also be "xyz.abc456.com" and it won't return a match. Will almost always return a 0 since the URL can never be an exact match.

**Also there are no common columns between the two to use in a join.**
Basically a substring search on one column from the column of another table.

Can anyone please suggest how I can do this? Thank you for your KQL-fu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different approaches to solve this:

**Approach #1** - this approach will work if LookupDomains has **no more** than 1,000,000 records:

```
let Urls = datatable(url: string) [
    "happydomain.com",
    "a.happydomain.com",
    "b.happydomain.com",
    "angrydomain.com",
    "a.angrydomain.com",
    "q1.a.angrydomain.com",
    "q2.a.angrydomain.com",
    "b.angrydomain.com",
    "q1.b.angrydomain.com",
    "q2.b.angrydomain.com",
    "surpriseddomain.co.il",
    "a.surpriseddomain.co.il",
    "b.surpriseddomain.co.il",
    "q1.a.surpriseddomain.co.il",
    "q2.b.surpriseddomain.co.il",
];
let LookupDomains = datatable(domain: string) [
    "happydomain.com",
    "a.angrydomain.com",
    "q1.a.surpriseddomain.co.il"
];
Urls
| extend dl = split(url, ".")
| extend dl1 = tostring(dl[-1])
| extend dl2 = strcat(dl[-2], ".", dl1)
| extend dl3 = strcat(dl[-3], ".", dl2)
| extend dl4 = strcat(dl[-4], ".", dl3)
| extend dl5 = strcat(dl[-5], ".", dl4)
| extend LoopupDomain =
        case(dl1 in (LookupDomains), dl1,
             dl2 in (LookupDomains), dl2,
             dl3 in (LookupDomains), dl3,
             dl4 in (LookupDomains), dl4,
             dl5 in (LookupDomains), dl5,
             "")
| where isnotempty(LoopupDomain)
| project-away dl*
```

Output:

| url | LoopupDomain |
| --- | --- |
| happydomain.com | happydomain.com |
| a.happydomain.com | happydomain.com |
| b.happydomain.com | happydomain.com |
| a.angrydomain.com | a.angrydomain.com |
| q1.a.angrydomain.com | a.angrydomain.com |
| q2.a.angrydomain.com | a.angrydomain.com |
| q1.a.surpriseddomain.co.il | q1.a.surpriseddomain.co.il |

If the `LookupDomains` table has more than 1,000,000 records, then the `in` approach above won't work, and the next approach will have to be used instead.

**Approach #2** - this approach will work regardless of the number of records in LookupDomains, but requires a little more work from your side:

First you'll need to add `dl2` as a separate column in the `Urls` and `LookupDomains` tables (this can be done as part of your ingestion flow, or using an [Update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)).

Then you'll need to use the following query instead of the query I wrote above:

```
LookupDomains
| join kind=inner Urls on dl2
| extend dl = split(url, ".")
| extend dl1 = tostring(dl[-1])
| extend dl3 = strcat(dl[-3], ".", dl2)
| extend dl4 = strcat(dl[-4], ".", dl3)
| extend dl5 = strcat(dl[-5], ".", dl4)
| where (dl1 == domain) or (dl2 == domain) or (dl3 == domain) or (dl4 == domain) or (dl5 == domain)
| project-away dl*
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the work you put in, instead of dismissing the question. Highly appreciate it! It looks like there is no straightforward way to achieve this , the way we do Select col1,col2 from Table1 where col1 In (select for another table).

Comment: You're welcome! While this is not trivial, it's definitely doable. I've also added a second approach to the answer, please take a look, you might find it useful too.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept my answer (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why). If you still need any info/clarification, feel free to ask by posting a comment here.